# Datagrid not showing table content

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have two table `masterdb` and `markssheetdb` table, and I want to fetch three columns of `masterdb` to `markssheedb` table from form 2 to form 1, but it throws an error like "**It will Generate duplicate values.**"

I'm using visual studio 2017 and Msaccess 2017.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Home
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\master.accdb"
        con.Open()

        Datagridshow()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Datagridshow()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO Smarkssheetdb ( ROLLNO, UNIVROLL, [NAMES] )
                                   SELECT Smasterdb.ROLL_No, Smasterdb.UNIV_ROLL, Smasterdb.NAME
                                    FROM Smasterdb,Smarkssheetdb where  Smasterdb.ROLL_No <> Smarkssheetdb.ROLLNO ", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddEditToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddEditToolStripMenuItem.Click
        addedit.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        End

    End Sub
End Class
```

In masterdb the rows are Sno, rollno, regno,univroll, course, name, sgpa1,sgpa2,.....,sgpa8 
and in markssheetdb table rows are rollno, univroll,name,m1,m2,m3,.....,m8

and I want the [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZcr.jpg) rollno, univroll, name in both the table will be same and if I update the masterdb then it will automatically update the markssheetdb table fields.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZcr.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/445pZ.jpg)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKpL.jpg)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgeGC.jpg)

Comment: Your database design is flawed. "I want the data rollno, univroll, name in both the table will be same" tells me that the design is not normalized. Find a DBA to help you with the design.

Comment: The fill method of a DataAdapter is used with Select commands not Insert.

Comment: Try that sql statement passed to the adapter in Access and see what your get.

Answer (score 0):

try your dataadapter without the insert statement

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Smasterdb.ROLL_No, Smasterdb.UNIV_ROLL, Smasterdb.NAME
                            FROM Smasterdb,Smarkssheetdb where  Smasterdb.ROLL_No <> Smarkssheetdb.ROLLNO;", con)
```

you should also try your select statements in access to see if they work properly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/XlaNT2V

Showing only data grid with 3 Columns and no data. But I want to like this 

https://imgur.com/iw33pyr

Comment: For that you can add CBOOL(False ) AS 1rst, CBOOL(False) AS 2sec and so on, but if have a condition, you can use that.